# error somewhere in if and else statements

Tags: c, if-statement

Most of this works correctly, however, i noticed if i try adding a negative integer, this happens:

The correct output line was:
Please enter two integers: negative one + three = two
Your program printed this line:
Please enter two integers:negativethree = two

The ifs after my "printf negative" if statement arent printing for some reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)  {
    int numOne;
    int numTwo; 
    printf("Please enter two integers:");
    scanf("%d%d", &numOne, &numTwo); 


    if (numOne >= -10 && numOne < 0) {
        printf("negative");    
    }
    if (numOne == 0) {
        printf("zero + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 1) {
        printf("one + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 2) {
        printf("two + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 3) {
        printf("three + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 4) {
        printf("four + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 5) {
        printf("five + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 6) {
        printf("six + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 7) {
        printf("seven + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 8) {
        printf("eight + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 9) {
        printf("nine + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 10) {
        printf("ten + ");
    } else if (numOne > 10 || numOne < -10) {
        printf("%d + ", numOne);
    }

    if (numTwo >= -10 && numTwo < 0) {
        printf("negative");    
    }
    if (numTwo == 0) {
        printf("zero");
    }
    if (numTwo == 1) {
        printf("one");
    }
    if (numTwo == 2) {
        printf("two");
    }
    if (numTwo == 3) {
        printf("three");
    }
    if (numTwo == 4) {
        printf("four");
    }
    if (numTwo == 5) {
        printf("five");
    }
    if (numTwo == 6) {
        printf("six");
    }
    if (numTwo == 7) {
        printf("seven");
    }
    if (numTwo == 8) {
        printf("eight");
    }
    if (numTwo == 9) {
        printf("nine");
    }
    if (numTwo == 10) {
        printf("ten");
    } else if (numTwo > 10 || numTwo < -10) {
        printf("%d = ", numTwo);
    }

    int total = numOne + numTwo;
    if (total >= -10 && total < 0) {
        printf(" = negative");    
    }
    if (total == 0) {
        printf(" = zero\n");
    }
    if (total == 1) {
        printf(" = one\n");
    }
    if (total == 2) {
        printf(" = two\n");
    }
    if (total == 3) {
        printf(" = three\n");
    }
    if (total == 4) {
        printf(" = four\n");
    }
    if (total == 5) {
        printf(" = five\n");
    }
    if (total == 6) {
        printf(" = six\n");
    }
    if (total == 7) {
        printf(" = seven\n");
    }
    if (total == 8) {
        printf(" = eight\n");
    }
    if (total == 9) {
        printf(" = nine\n");
    }
    if (total == 10) {
        printf(" = ten\n");
    } else if (total > 10 || total < -10) {
        printf(" = %d\n", total);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if the number is negative you need to change it to positive inside the first `if` for the rest of the code to work.

Comment: And to pass auto marker: `printf("negative")` needs a space at the end of the string.

Comment: : 0 aa thats a rlly efficient fix ty!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change sign of the variable when it's negative. Like:

```
if (numOne >= -10 && numOne < 0) {
    printf("negative");    
    numOne = -numOne;
}
```

Then the rest of the code only needs to handle positive values.

It requires that you reorganize some of the other code. For instance this:

```
int total = numOne + numTwo;
```

must be moved so it's done just after the `scanf`

Also consider using an array of strings instead of all the `if` statements.
Like:

```
char numberToText[11][10] = {"zero", "one", "two", ... , "ten"};
```

Then you can do

```
if (numOne < -10 || numOne  > 10)
{
    // special handling
}
else
{
    if (numOne < 0) numOne = -numOne;   // Change sign if negative
    printf("%s", numberToText[numOne]);
}
```

If you don't want to change the value of `numOne`, just use another variable:

```
if (numOne < -10 || numOne  > 10)
{
    // special handling
}
else
{
    int tmp = numOne;        // Copy to another variable and
    if (tmp < 0) tmp = -tmp; // make sure it's positive

    printf("%s", numberToText[tmp]);   // Use tmp as index
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you used `char numberToText[11][10] = ...` - there's no reason to change this data at any point and it seems wasteful when you could just use `char *numberToText[] = ...`

Comment: Actually, I see that as the *opposite* of KISS, you're specifying something that's totally unnecessary and prone to error should the values ever change (such as in a different language).  Using the C auto-sizing and string literals is actually simpler. And you might want to temper the accusations just a little, I'm sure any of the *other* twelve million or so members could have downvoted you. Unless you really *are* thanking me in a non-sarcastic way, in which case maybe I should claim credit and take the kudos :-) In fact, were you to get rid of that, I may even upvote you ...

Comment: But probably not, since you've done little to alleviate the real problem, the rather voluminous sequence of `if` statements, which are better done as data-driven stuff. Oh, yeah, and the unfounded accusation :-) Not saying your answer is *wrong* since you solved the immediate problem. I, however, prefer to educate as part of the process. Doesn't always earn me rep but it is useful, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you capture a negative number (to insert "negative") but then only check the numbers `1..10` for outputting the magnitude.

The simplest fix is probably to change:

```
if (numOne == 1) {
    printf("one + ");
}
```

into:

```
if (numOne == 1 || numOne == -1) {
    printf("one + ");
}
```

Ditto for all the other ones of course.

---

Or, alternatively, you can *greatly* reduce the complexity with a function like:

```
void outputNum(char *pre, int num, char *post) {
    static const char* lookup[] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three",
        "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
    if (num < -10 || num > 10) {
        printf("%s%d%s", pre, num, post);
    } else {
        if (num < 0)
            printf("%snegative %s%s", pre, lookup[-num], post);
        else
            printf("%s%s%s", pre, lookup[num], post);
    }
}
```

and just call it with a simple:

```
outputNum("Adding ", num1, "");
outputNum(" and ", num2, "");
outputNum(" gives you ", num1 + num2, "\n");
```